# Irreducibility of a certain matrix variety

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, symmetric-polynomials

Let $R=\mathbb{Q}[x_{i,j}\,:\, 1\leq i,j\leq n]$.  Let $M$ be the $n\times n$ matrix $(x_{i.j})$.  Let $\chi(M)$ be the characteristic polynomial of $M$.  Finally, let $I$ be the ideal of $R$ generated by the non-constant coefficients of $\chi(M)$.

It should be well known that $I$ is a prime ideal of $R$.  Is there a good reference for this fact?

Comment: You are asking for a reference proving that the nilpotent cone is integral (irreducible and reduced).

Comment: [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nilpotent_cone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nilpotent_cone)

Comment: The better theorem (since it's obviously connected, being a cone) is that it's normal, due to Kostant.